# RedPitaya case or housing options?

Tags: printing, 3d-model, oscilloscope, redpitaya

The RedPitaya is a great looking instrument, but I'm afraid that I'll kill my new (expensive) device by stray voltage or ESD off my bench, within a few days.

Is it planned to make an optional "professional" case or similar to protect it?

Has anyone already created a 3D model so a printable case or housing could be made?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.  I guess I'll get started on designing a 3D model for printing in PLA.

Comment: I made a first pass at designing a case.  I haven't printed it yet, since my printer is between upgrades ;)  But, it should provide a simple base and sides at least: http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:263581

Answer (score 2):

As a quick fix, I would:

- use a piece of plain printer paper on the bench, underneath the Red Pitaya (it's typically more conductive than a typical plastic coating on the bench, but still not so cunductive as to short anything on the board bottom), and
- more importantly, each time when approaching the bench, first touch the outside of one of the golden SMA jacks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably any quick google search would answer the question but for the sake of completeness, I will answer this quesiton with what I found in my quick search.

## Purchase Options

Now a days, there are several cases available for the pitaya:

- Available on RS-components, Reichelt, amoung others:

  - RS Code: RS819-4077
  - Manufacturer: Red Pitaya
  - Manufacturer Ref: 1600 0715 001
  - Approximate cost: 20 Euros + Shipping + taxes
- What appears to be 3d printed providers:

  - [Nylon Plastic closed top case](http://www.shapeways.com/product/7TRZ83VSG/red-pitaya-enclosure-top-closed-version) : Approximate 30 Euros
  - [Nylon Plastic open top case](http://www.shapeways.com/product/HE5YCUCT3/red-pitaya-enclosure-top-open-version)

## Printing Options

If you happen to have your own 3D printer then you can print one of many available designs.

- [Closed Top case](https://grabcad.com/library/enclosure-red-pitaya-ecosystem-closed-top-1)
- [Open Top case](https://grabcad.com/library/enclosure-red-pitaya-ecosystem-open-top-1)
- A Shielded Case [Github Prject](https://github.com/hzeller/RedPitaya-Case), on [Thingiverse](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:278113), on [Youmagine](https://www.youmagine.com/designs/shielded-redpitaya-case)

Others can be found on http://www.yeggi.com/ , http://grabcad.com/ ,...